# multiple excerpt length in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the following function for an excerpt in Wordpress.

```
<?php

// Excerpt - end of sentence

function custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ('' == $text) {

        // Retrieve the post content.

        $text = get_the_content('');

        // Delete all shortcode tags from the content.

        $text = strip_shortcodes($text);
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
        $allowed_tags = '<i>,<strong>';
        $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);
        $excerpt_word_count = 40;
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count);
        $excerpt_end = '...' . '<div class="read-more"><a class="button" href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read More' . '</a></div>';
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);
        $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if (count($words) > $excerpt_length) {
            array_pop($words);
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
            $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
        }
        else {
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }
    }

    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

I want to add a second word count to use on the blog page.  The above word count is being used on the front page. Advice, please? Thanks.

Comment: Use if condition to check if it is a front page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
function custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
   if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
     // Excerpt for front page or home page

   } else {
     // Excerpt for rest of the site

   }
}

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

By using this piece of code you have more control over the excerpt that is outputted on different pages.

If that worked mark your question as solved.